# How to compare vector?

Tags: c++, vector

How to compare two vectors? Both cointains integer values:

```
void interaction(vehicles::position &pos, int number, enviroment object)
{
    for (auto i = object.x.begin(); i<object.x.end(); i++)
        for (auto j = object.y.begin(); j<object.y.end(); j++)
            if (pos.x[number] == object.x[i] && pos.y[number] == object.y[j])
                cout << "\nInteraction\n";
}
```

First vector (declared in class):

```
int remaining_move;
     struct position{
         vector<int> x;
         vector<int> y;
     }pos;
```

Second:

```
struct enviroment
{
    vector<int> x;
    vector<int> y;
    string graphic;
};
```

Errors:
[image: errors]

Comment: Please reproduce the error text in the question, instead of posting a screenshot.

Comment: Sort the vectors, and then call `==`:  `std::sort(a.begin(), a,end()); std::sort(b.begin(), b.end()); return a == b;`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The question is - how to compare these two vectors? I put these errors only to ilustrate where is the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> object.x[i]
> ```

This is wrong. It would work if `i` were a numeric index, but it's not: it's an iterator.

Instead:

```
*i
```

I therefore further suggest calling it something other than `i`; how about `it`?

<strike>Also, your inner loop condition is wrong. You wrote `i`, rather than `j`. Twice.</strike> *[edit: and now you've fixed that in the question, for some reason]*

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend sorting them first, so this is how I would do it:

```
std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());
std::vector<int> v3;
std::set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::back_inserter(v3));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for `pos.x[number]` and `pos.y[number]` in `object.x` and `object.y`, respectively, why not just:

```
auto itX = std::find(object.x.begin(), object.x.end(), pos.x[number]);
auto itY = std::find(object.y.begin(), object.y.end(), pos.y[number]);

if (itX != object.x.end() && itY != object.y.end()) {
    std::cout << "\nInteraction\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare one vector element, you compare the value in the slots:

```
std::vector<int> a;
std::vector<int> b;
//...
if (a[0] == b[0])
{
  // elements are equal
}
```

More elements can be compared by using a loop:

```
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
  {
    if (a[i] != b[i])
    {
       break;
    }
  }
```

One of the thorns is when the vectors are of different sizes.  You'll have to decide on what your actions are on that topic.

There are probably some algorithms in `<algorithm>` that you can use on a vector.